# Adding Multiple Values to Single Key in Python Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I am using a dictionary comprension to be created from an excel spreadsheet. The first column of the excel sheet are the keys and the next 3 columns are the values. I'd like to build a dictionary comprehension that I can use later in my script. I understand a dictionary comprehension to be built as:

```
d = {key: value for (key, value) in sequence}
```

and I can do this and get a nice key,value dictionary:

```
d = {str(row.getValue("Column1")): str(row.getValue("Column2")) for i in arcpy.SearchCursor(xls,"[Column1] = 'Lake_Huron'")}
```

I'm just not sure how I would go about adding the other 2 columns in the dictionary comprehension as 2nd and 3rd values to the key? Is this possible?

Comment: You mean in the `key` or in the `value`?

Comment: I want to add multiple values to each key. So column1: column2,column3,column4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {str(row.getValue("Column1")): (str(row.getValue("Column2")), str(row.getValue("Column3")), str(row.getValue("Column4"))) for i in arcpy.SearchCursor(xls,"[Column1] = 'Lake_Huron'")}
```

OR

```
d = {str(row.getValue("Column1")): (str(row.getValue("Column{0}".format(i)) for i in [2, 3, 4]) for i in arcpy.SearchCursor(xls,"[Column1] = 'Lake_Huron'")}
```

Comment: Actually, I like the second method, however I am returning a generator object for the values. I'm not sure how to unpack that to make it readable. If I did, I see an opportunity to be able to filter out values that = None which is my next step.

Comment: You can use a generator object in place of an iterable.

Comment: Ugh, this is where I suck. I don't know much about revealing the contents of a generator object. I tried using d.values, but it keets returning the generator object experession, where I actually want the values. How would I do that?

Comment: you can just do `for i in generator_object`

Comment: I think I'm confused. In the first example you provided, I get a nice list of values {'Lake_Huron': ('Lake_NUMBER_ID', 'Size', 'None')} in the second example I get {'Lake_Huron': <generator object <genexpr> at 0x14B15418>} How do I convert the generator object syntax back to a list list so that it looks like the first dictionary?